# Is this good practice for caching database data on my HTTP servlet?

Tags: java, android, jsp, servlets, caching

I'm writing an HTTP servlet (Hosted on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk) that serves as an application server for my Android app. My application will request data from my servlet, which will in turn pull from the database (SimpleDB).

Since my client requests may be frequent, I wanted to implement a cache on my servlet that will cache the requested data so as to cut down on database reads. Currently, I just initialize a "ServerCache" object as a member variable of my servlet. ServerCache contains lists for cached data, and I populate these as I go.

Looks something like this.

```
public class ServerCache {
/**
 * ServerCache is responsible for caching data on the server.
 * Create several data structures on the server to cache buy/sell listings as listing objects. 
 * For now, we will be able to cache the entirety of the database contents. 
 * -ES
 * 
 * Only one ServerCache should ever be made, at the init() of this server
 */

private List<BuyListing> listbl; //What is the danger of having this public vs. private
private List<SellListing> listsl;

public String BLlastError;
public String SLlastError;
public ServerCache()
{
    this.listbl = new ArrayList<BuyListing>();
    this.listsl = new ArrayList<SellListing>();

    this.BLlastError = "Initialized";
    this.SLlastError = "Initialized";
} //Setters and getters ommitted
```

And it is initialized here

```
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {

private SimpleDBConnect SDB; // contains functions for accessing database
private ServerCache Cache;

//Various Constants
private static final String BUY_LISTINGS_DOMAIN = "BuyListings";
private static final String SELL_LISTINGS_DOMAIN = "SellListings";
private static final String USER_ID_DOMAIN = "UserIDs";
private static final String MESSAGES_DOMAIN = "Messages";



public HelloWorld() {
    super();
    SDB = new SimpleDBConnect();
    SDB.createConnection();
    Cache = new ServerCache();

    Cache.setListbl(SDB.getAllBL());
    Cache.setListsl(SDB.getAllSL());
    updateSDBStatus();
    updateServletStatus("Initialized");
    updateCacheStatus();

}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    response.getOutputStream().println("Servlet Works \n SimpleDB Status:" + SDB.dbConnectStatus + "\n \n SDB log:  " + this.SDBStatus + "\n \n Servlet log:    " + this.ServletStatus
            + "\n \n Buy Cache Status:  " + this.BLCacheStatus + "\n \n Sell Cache Status:  " + this.SLCacheStatus);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
// ... Some code ommitted, the following is a relevant part of how I handle request for data

         if (packet.getHeader() == Constants.BL_REQUEST || packet.getHeader() == Constants.SL_REQUEST)
            {               
                MsgStruct temp = new MsgStruct();   
                if (packet.getHeader() == Constants.BL_REQUEST){
                    temp.setHeader(Constants.BL_REQUEST);

                    Type listOfTestObject = new TypeToken<List<BuyListing>>(){}.getType();
                    String s = gson.toJson(Cache.getListbl(), listOfTestObject);

                    temp.setPayload(s);
                    receivedString = gson.toJson(temp);
                }
```

Is there any reason why caching a version of the data on my servlet will be a bad idea? This is just my stab in the dark, as nobody has ever taught me what to do in this case. I'm aware that concurrency is an issue, but I dont think it should matter in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a cache into the program will complicate it a little bit, specifically when you want to modify the data. In this case, the database and the cache should always have the same data, no matter what `GET` or `POST` requests are received that may or may not write to the database.

A problem you may run into is how to keep the cache in sync with the database. It will be crucial to always update the cache when writing to the database, and make sure that when you fulfill a request with the cache, that you return the same data as is contained in the database. You did say that you're only caching data requested, but if data is ever written back to the database, you will have to check that cached data is also updated.

You mentioned that you'll only instantiate one instance of the class. It might make more sense to follow the singleton pattern for the cache, see the Wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern for more information.  Basically, this causes the cache to initialize itself and make sure no other code can make another instance. The constructor will be private, and you would write a `getInstance()` method to have the cache return the instantiated `ServerCache` object.

The reason I'm going this route is because there's always a possibility that you will write another servlet that needs to access the database, and it will be difficult to give it cache access without making the cache a singleton (not to mention multithreading issues associated with multiple reads).

Another thing to remember, your cache will take up RAM on the server. Caching trades of RAM usage for access time, and depending on your plan, you may or may not have a lot of that to spare. It's also a real possibility that you'd just replicate your entire database in RAM, defeating its purpose. You would spend a bunch of processing time making sure you update the database but never actually use it. So again, if you see an improvement in responsiveness, I see no problem with it, as long as you manage it well.

To effectively use a cache, you'd have to keep a strict limit on the number of cached objects, getting rid of objects that aren't used much, keeping only the ones that are accessed very frequently. A final point I want to make is that I noticed your cache is using ArrayLists. Those aren't the most efficient data structures for searching unsorted data. A database is *made* for data storage, so the database most likely has a more efficient storage system anyway, which in your case would make a cache only useful for very small amounts of frequently accessed but seldom modified data.